# I have a scroll in a scroll, but I want them independent of each other. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in a div. the table is more height than the div. I have a vertical scroll to navigate into the div to show the table lines.
The first line has a bootstrap select and it contains a scroll. It makes like this:
[image: result]

```
<div class="content-tab" id="guest">
    <table id="guestTable" class="tableClass">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:10% !important;max-width:150px !important;">*</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Tous</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Lun</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Mar</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Mer</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Jeu</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Ven</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Sam</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Dim</th>
                <th class="text-center">*</th>
                <th class="text-center">*</th>
                <th class="text-center"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="GuestBody">
            <tr id="newPlanning">
                <td style="width:10% !important;max-width:150px !important;"><select id="Articles" class="selectpicker"
                        data-live-search="true" old-value="" style="display: none;">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="59863">*</option>
                        <option value="59969">*</option>
                        <option value="59999">*</option>
                        <option value="60078">*</option>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </select>
                    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select open"><button type="button"
                            class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            data-id="Articles" title="Articles" aria-expanded="true"><span
                                class="filter-option pull-left">Articles</span>&nbsp;<span
                                class="caret"></span></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 540px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 123px;">
                            <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="input-block-level form-control"
                                    autocomplete="off"></div>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu"
                                style="max-height: 488px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 71px;">
                                <li data-original-index="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class=""><span class="text"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                                <li data-original-index="1" class=""><a tabindex="0" class=""><span class="text">*</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                                <li data-original-index="2" class=""><a tabindex="0" class=""><span class="text">*</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                                <li data-original-index="3" class=""><a tabindex="0" class=""><span class="text">*</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                                <li data-original-index="4" class=""><a tabindex="0" class=""><span class="text">*</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                                <li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class=""><span class="text">*</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                                .
                                .
                                .
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="0123456" type="text" id="0123456" maxlength="1" onclick="this.select();" onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="0" type="text" id="0" maxlength="1" onclick="this.select();" onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="1" type="text" id="1"maxlength="1" onclick="   this.select();"onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="2" type="text" id="2"maxlength="1" onclick="   this.select();"onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="3" type="text" id="3"maxlength="1" onclick="   this.select();"onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="4" type="text" id="4"maxlength="1" onclick="   this.select();"onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="5" type="text" id="5"maxlength="1" onclick="   this.select();"onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td class=""><input class="form-control input-sm" data-day-week="6" type="text" id="6"maxlength="1" onclick="   this.select();"onkeypress="return RecurrencePopin.verifyNumbers(event, this);" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td><label><input type="text" class="form-control actual_rangeC" id="startDate" value="03/07/2019"></label></td>
                <td><label><input type="text" class="form-control actual_rangeC" id="endDate" value="03/07/2019"></label></td>
                <td class="actionCol text-center pull-right" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="btnAddPlanning" title="Ajouter une programmation" class="btnAdd icon-plus hidden"></div> </td>
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I expect that I see the entire list of the select over the div. Now it's in the div, I see some option not all.

Comment: If you have overflow:hidden on a parent element, any child outside of that element's bounding box will be hidden.You can either make your div bigger, your options smaller, or remove the overflow:hidden altogether.

Comment: Are there other solutions? because I have many options as you can see in the screenshot. I have other information to show. So I can't make the div bigger.

Comment: What do you mean "other information" ? How many records does the table contain ? You could try and add pagination to your table instead of overflow:hidden. It would look nicer too.

Comment: I can not beacause I show you a part of the modal not the entire.
[link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4107566/96caeca44d8075ee99c04fb96740c1b0)

Comment: What you can do, is to make the modal scrollable and add more height to the div with overflow:hidden.

Comment: This is not user friendly. I don't do that.

Comment: A friend found for me a solution with css. this is not the solution but work for me
I do that on the element
{position: fixed;
top: 312px;
left: 48px;
width: 300px;}

Comment: I made a little example here of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/tzwvh4rm/ 
But if your friend found a solution, and if you like it, than just use your friend's solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will hold my friend solution.